# Best way to handle monthly subscription allowance with Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

What will be the best pratice to compute monthly allowance of our service when using a Stripe monthly subscription?

I can see 2 strategies:

1. Add usage to a monthly usage hash (ie. `{month_1: 342, month_2: 20}`). Calculate current month based on the Stripe subscription `start` date. Kind of ignore variance in Stripe subscription actual renewal dates, and require manual intervention to block a customer if renewal doesn't go through.
2. Have a `monthy_allowance` (credit counter still avaiable for the current month) variable that is replenish when Stripe fires the successful subscription renewal web hook. It's more tie to the actual subscription status, but I can see being an issue as it seems harder to test and subject to bugs if the web hook doesn't properly receive the event. Can be an issue if some customers got locked out until we manually allow them back in.

I suppose it doesn't really matter in this question, but we are using `Ruby on Rails` with `MongoDB` as backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about having some kind of 'usage credit' that your users will 'use up', and that is replenished when a Subscription charge is made, I think you could likely handle this by just having a bucket (like, a counter) that you draw down when they use something, and you fill up when the Subscription is successfully paid, and where you block them (or provide a way to buy more) when the bucket hits zero.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it's what I was thinking doing with (2). I wonder if anyone has any issue relying so much on Stripe web hooks to define credit (what I called allowance) ?

Comment: Stripe's webhooks are usually pretty quick; there will be about an hour between when the invoice is created and when it is paid, so there is that to consider as well.

Comment: I see. 1 hour is not a big deal. Do you know a way to get the renewal date in an accurate way? Like if the subscription started on the 31 of January, when will be it renewed in February?

Comment: There are a bunch of details about that stuff here: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/lifecycle fit yes, Jan 31 would be Feb 28/29, Mar 31, Apr 30, etc.